# Pixel 7 Pro won't connect to specific WiFi network

Tags: google-pixel

I've had a Pixel 7 Pro since release and it's been working fine until a week or so ago when it steadfastly refuses to connect to a specific home WiFi network.

Every other device in the house works fine on this network (as did the P7P until a week ago) and the P7P worked absolutely fine over Xmas whilst I was away at my parents using a different network, however it totally refuses to connect to my home network.

My network is an eero mesh network (not eero 6). I've tried resetting the WiFi on my phone and unplugging the network etc. The only thing I've not done is reset the phone (as suggested by Google online support).

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off wpa3 in the eero app. This just happened to me, p7p w eero pro.

Comment: This worked for me.